# Why I long press an list cause the app crash uwp?

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm migrating my app to UWP and I found one problem. That is when I long press  or hold an item inside the listview, app will crash and exit. I already tried to handle the `Holding` event by myself. But it doesn't work. After execute the `OnHolding` event which I registered and do nothing inside it, it just exit without any trace (I cannot use F10 to step by step debug it, it just exit without any information). Any idea?  This only happens in Win10 phone.

```
 private void OnHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

The code for ShowLayout.Execute()

```
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);

        return null;
    }
```

and here is the xaml code about the Flyout item

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout
            Closed="OnFlyoutClosed"
            Opening="OnFlyoutOpening">

            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style
                    TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Light"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PlacementStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="None" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="TopPortrait">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransformOrigin" Duration="0:0:0" To="0,1" />
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,1.5" />
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CenterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,1.5" />
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitThemePadding}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Duration="0:0:0.38" From="0.0" To="1.0" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.38" Value="0.0" />
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="1.0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomPortrait">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransformOrigin" Duration="0:0:0" To="0,1" />
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,1.5" />
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CenterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,1.5" />
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPortraitThemePadding}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Duration="0:0:0.38" From="0.0" To="1.0" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.38" Value="0.0" />
                                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.50" Value="1.0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftLandscape">

                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="RightLandscape">

                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="OuterScaleTransform" />
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Border x:Name="CenterBorder" Margin="12" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" BorderBrush="{StaticResource XX.ColorBrush.WG}" BorderThickness="2.5">
                                        <StackPanel x:Name="InnerBorder" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="InnerScaleTransform" />
                                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>

            <MenuFlyoutItem
                Click="xx"
                Text="{Binding xx" />

            <MenuFlyoutItem .../>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Comment: Can I see  your XAML portion? Not sure could be some style is breaking. Check for SelectedPressedBackground state style in your code.

Comment: Please show your XAML code, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @KiranPaul I tested it a little bit and found that it is the ShowFlyoutBehavior defined in this app caused the program which is another UWP incompatibility problem

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I tested it a little bit and found that it is the ShowFlyoutBehavior defined in this app caused the program which is another UWP incompatibility problem

Comment: @KiranPaul I added the code behind,  if this is the correct way to do it in UWP, then I think I need to post the long xaml code.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I added the code behind,  if this is the correct way to do it in UWP, then I think I need to post the long xaml code.

Comment: @KiranPaul I just updated the xaml, thank  you!

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I just updated the xaml, thank  you!

Comment: I tested your code, the problem is with your `MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle`, when remove this style, the error won't occur. Even the app won't crash on PC, your transform in your style is not displayed.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Yes, I commented this out  and it works. Thank you!

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Recently  I got lots of broken style in UWP which works fine in Win8.1. Here is one that only breaks in SP,  not desk mode,  not for phone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143248/why-pivot-will-cause-crash-when-clicking-and-tapping-but-swiping-works-fine-in Could you take a look and share some idea, please? Thank you!