# Why pivot will cause crash when clicking and tapping(only Surface not desktop not phone), but swiping works fine in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm upgrading my app to UWP and found that when I swipe the pivot item it works fine while clicking|tapping will cause app crash. This only happens in SP not in desktop mode nor phone. I do think this style is broken, but have no idea why it will fail and how to  fix it. Any idea?

```
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource XX.ColorBrush.BB1}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Got a stack trace? There must be an exception somewhere.

Comment: @Fred I didn't get any exception, even though I did checked almost all of them in the Exception Settings. However, I got error  something like Access failure when it exits. There is no line number or anything to let me know which part of the code is wrong

Comment: In your App.xaml.cs constructor you can add this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException; and then inspect all uncatched exceptions in this method.

Comment: @Fred, I did have it in my app.xaml.cs like this private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e), however, it never gets called in this situation

Comment: I don't have a SP so I can't test it, but I can understand that you added a `Foreground` setter in the style and removed the preview and next button of pivot. But I came to be aware, you are migrating your old apps to UWP app, the styles and resources from other versions of the SDK might have different values. As you said in your last case that a lot of your styles broken in the UWP are, this could be a reason. Here are [Default control styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx) for UWP app, may be you need to override you old style.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I think this is exactly what I want. I will dive into it and find out how to upgrade my style to UWP. Thank you so much!